# Can't get focus on a TextBox inside a ListBox using Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, xaml, silverlight-4.0

I'm having a little trouble in silverlight with a databound ListBox containing databound TextBox elements. The items display correctly in the list and the TextBox is populated correctly but I can't get focus on the TextBox in the list. If I hover over the edges of the TextBox it highlights but it won't let me click into it to edit the text. Any ideas?

My XAML looks like this:

```
<ListBox x:Name="listImages">
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
        <Image Height="102" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="imgThumb" Stretch="UniformToFill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="155" Source="{Binding ImageFilename, Converter={StaticResource ImageConverter}}" />
        <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="154,25,0,0" Name="txtAltText" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="239" Text="{Binding Alt}" />
        <dataInput:Label Height="19" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="154,6,0,0" Name="lblAltText" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="239" Content="Alt Text" />
      </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Which silverlight version do you use?

Comment: I'm using silverlight 4 for this

Comment: For test purposes can you remove the image?  Without the image it works just fine for me.

Comment: Thanks Anthony, you pointed me in the right direction. It was having an issue with the Grid. I've swapped the grid out with a StackPanel and it works fine with the Image in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I swapped the content for this and it now works, I think it was having an issue with the Grid container:

```
<ListBox x:Name="listImages">
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Image Height="102" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="imgThumb" Stretch="UniformToFill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="155" Source="{Binding ImageFilename, Converter={StaticResource ImageConverter}}" Margin="5" />
        <StackPanel>
          <dataInput:Label Height="19" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="lblAltText" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="239" Content="Alt Text" />
          <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="txtAltText" VerticalAlignment="Top" Text="{Binding Alt}" />
        </StackPanel>
      </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```